# To use the confluent hypergeometric function or not to?

Tags: integration, quadrature, special-functions

I am numerically computing the following integral as a function of positive $k$.
$$I(k) := \int_0^\infty x^b(k+x)^{a-1} e^{-x} dx \tag1$$
[It is shown in math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3703382/64809) that this can be expressed as the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind
$$I(k) = k^{a+b} \Gamma(b+1)\, U(b+1, a+b+1, k)  \tag2$$ 
under the condition $k>0, \Re(b)>-1$.

For $k\to 0^+$, $I(k)\to \Gamma(a+b)$, while $U(b+1,a+b+1,k)\sim\frac1{k^{a+b}}$. So there is a problem of multiplying a small number with a large number to get a finite number, not a numerically ideal situation. If I use the Python package Scipy, is it more accurate to evaluate the integral $(1)$ directly with Scipy.integrate.quad, or use the confluent hypergeometric function module scipy.special and compute $U$ via expression $(2)$? Or should I divide the axis of $k$ into two parts $[0, K]$ and $[K,\infty)$ and evaluate $I(k)$ on the left interval via $(1)$ and the right interval via $(2)$? If so, how should I choose the best $K$?